# Limited Length to slug field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

How can I give the limit to slug field in the database.In the Below code question is the field of table and it contains the long text.so i want to create slug for question field with limited length.How can I?
//In Model

```
var $actsAs = array(
            'Sluggable.Sluggable' => array(
            'label' => 'question',
            'slug' => 'slug',
            'separator' => '-',
            'overwrite' => false
          )
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [source for the behaviour](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/Model/Behavior/SluggableBehavior.php).

Simply add the `'length'=>50` param to your sluggable array.

Most of CakeDC's plugins are excellent but lack in documentation (which should encourage you to do your own work in understanding how the plugin works).

Answer (score -1):

create a function

```
   function create_slug($string) {
      $string = substr($string, 0, 100);
      $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $string);
      $string = strtolower(trim($string, '-'));
      $string = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", '-', $string);
      return $string;
    }
```

and use it like this

```
$actsAs = array(
    'Sluggable.Sluggable' => array(
        'label' => 'very & long & question',
        'slug' => create_slug('very & long & question'),
        'separator' => '-',
        'overwrite' => false
    )
);

print_r($actsAs);
```

// ouptut

```
Array
(
    [Sluggable.Sluggable] => Array
        (
            [label] => very & long & question
            [slug] => very-long-question
            [separator] => -
            [overwrite] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: If am writing like this it shows an errorclass Faq extends AppModel {
 var $name = 'Faq';
         var $actsAs = array(
            'Sluggable.Sluggable' => array(
            'label' => 'question',
     'slug' => create_slug('question'),
            'separator' => '-',
            'overwrite' => false
          )
        );